# Creating a New Variable in SPSS with a Value Equal to Another Variable

Tags: if-statement, spss

I apologize for the confusing title. Essentially, the intended functionality in SPSS is working with the following data file:

```
Monday     Tuesday     Wednesday     Day of Interest    Temperature on Day of interest
72         78          80            2
```

Here we have three variables and then the temperature for each of those days. The goal is to create a new variable, in the example it's Temperature on Day of Interest, that has the same value as the day it corresponds to (e.g. The second day of the week is a Monday, so we want to temperature on Monday in the new variable column). So the outcome of the syntax should make the data file read:

```
Monday     Tuesday     Wednesday     Day of Interest    Temperature on Day of interest
72         78          80            2                    72
```

My thoughts are that I can use an If statement, but I'm not sure on exactly how the syntax would be in SPSS. Here is what I have written:

```
IF (Day of Interest = 2) Temperature on Day of Interest = $Monday.
IF (Day of Interest = 3) Temperature on Day of Interest = $Tuesday.
```

Does anyone happen to know how to properly reference the value in various variables in this manner? I hope this is clear, I'll be able to answer any questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating some fake data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday  Day_of_Interest    .
begin data
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 2
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 6
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 4
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 7
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 1
end data.
```

Now it is possible of course to work with separate IF statements like this:

```
IF (Day_of_Interest = 2) Temperature_on_Day_of_interest = Monday.
IF (Day_of_Interest = 3) Temperature_on_Day_of_interest = Tuesday.
IF (Day_of_Interest = 4) Temperature_on_Day_of_interest = Wednesday.
EXECUTE.
```

But instead of creating seven separate statements for seven days, you can use a loop this way:

```
do repeat Dname=Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday/Dval=1 2 3 4 5 6 7.
IF (Day_of_Interest = Dval) Temperature_on_Day_of_interest = Dname.
end repeat.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Thanks @eli-k, this is exactly my intended functionality. Thank you greatly for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution(s) provided by eli-k shall more than suffice however if you have a large dataset then you are evaluating the `IF` condition 7 x number cases in your dataset and no less, something to be conscious of.

If, however, you use `DO IF/END IF` then you can achieve the same result with only looping through all the cases just once. On large datasets this could have big implications on processing time.

```
do if Day_of_Interest=1.
  compute Temperature=Sunday.
else if Day_of_Interest=2.
  compute Temperature=Monday.
else if Day_of_Interest=3.
  compute Temperature=Tuesday.
else if Day_of_Interest=4.
  compute Temperature=Wednesday.
else if Day_of_Interest=5.
  compute Temperature=Thursday.
else if Day_of_Interest=6.
  compute Temperature=Friday.
else if Day_of_Interest=7.
  compute Temperature=Saturday.
end if.
```

You may have to write more lines of code as above but you need to balance writing compact/parsimonious code vs. processing time. You could take this a step further where you list in the code each `DO IF` statement in descending frequency of `Day_of_Interest`. These are in principle some of the techniques used in processing large datasets.

Comment: Thanks, that's something that's good to keep in mind. The data set is has around 10 million cases, so that is especially good to keep in mind. Unfortunately, I have to use IF statements as my colleagues are not experienced with loops and they may need to do similar operations. Nonetheless, I really appreciate your time and thank you for your thoughtful and spot-on answer.

Comment: There is nothing more complicated in using `DO IF` vs. `IF`.